# Inside working mysql at JOIN query

Tags: mysql, join

Suppose we have 2 table

table1:

```
 column
 ------
 A
 B
```

and table2:

```
 column
 ------
 B
 C
 D
```

Now suppose I run a `JOIN` command with these two tables.  What happens inside mysql when running the JOIN query? Does MySQL create a virtual table like this?

```
 A|B
 A|C
 A|D
 B|B
 B|C
 B|D
```

Comment: What is your query?  My guess is you forgot a `WHERE` or `ON`

Comment: Does no matters what is condition, Ok, first, mysql must create joined virtual table right? and then retrieve result from this table according to condition, I am asking: How looks like virtual table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're creating a `JOIN` between two tables without any join parameters, MySQL takes a look at the first table in your statement.

It fetches the value, in your case 'A', and then pairs every value from the second table to it. When that's done, it's back to the first table, where the next value (in your case 'B') is fetched, and again, every value from the second table gets paired to it.

A sort of graphical explanation:

[image]